# Delete query using join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Delete  mfg_product_specification 
from mfg_product_specification
join dbo.spec_attribute  on mfg_product_specification.attribute_id=spec_attribute.attribute_id 
where spec_attribute.attribute_name = 'MEMSEL_SLOTS_NUM'
and mfg_product_specification.mfg_product_id in (247174) 
and  mfg_product_specification.value=''
```

I would like to delete the record from `mfg_product_specification` table. Do i need to specify `mfg_product_specification` after `delete`? Is there any other way using `delete` statement using `join` statement? Is the above the best way or only way to do it, or can my join be modified to do a `delete` as well in a safer process?

Comment: Please note you don't need a select statement for deleting. I edited your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks good and it is a safe way to use a join. Yes, when you are joining two tables, then you need to define one table name after the `delete` statement.

I would just recommend to write `inner join` instead of `join`. It is the same, but it makes more clear that you really want an `inner join`, and not a `left join` or `right join`.

```
Delete  mfg_product_specification 
from mfg_product_specification
    inner join dbo.spec_attribute  on mfg_product_specification.attribute_id=spec_attribute.attribute_id 
where spec_attribute.attribute_name = 'MEMSEL_SLOTS_NUM'
    and mfg_product_specification.mfg_product_id in (247174) 
    and  mfg_product_specification.value=''
```

Answer (score -2):

I tend to prefer using `exists` in this context:

```
Delete  ps
from mfg_product_specification ps
where ps.mfg_product_id in (247174) and
      ps.value = '' and
      exists (select 1
              from dbo.spec_attribute sa
              where ps.attribute_id = sa.attribute_id and
                    sa.attribute_name = 'MEMSEL_SLOTS_NUM'
             );
```

I find the logic easier to follow:  remove records from `ps` that meeting the following conditions.

I simply don't associate `JOIN` with `DELETE` -- and that is because `JOIN` conceptually creates a "new result" which is essentially a subset of the Cartesian product, removed from the original tables.  In addition, `EXISTS` guarantees that each row is only attempted to be deleted once.  However, `JOIN` could generate multiple copies of a row, if the `JOIN` is not 1-1.